# Why can't I edit a text again in TextInput using state of hooks?

Tags: react-native

I'm currently developing an application using React Native.

This trial app has a component that has a TextInput and two buttons (ADD and DELETE).

When I press the ADD Button, a new component appears. If I press the DELETE Button that the same component disappears.

I control the TextInput with the index which is the same number as the index of the component.

The screen is like the photo bellow:
[image]

---

In this code, there is a bug when I edit some text I already inputes.
For Exanple:

1. enter some text at the input area index[0], then it works well.
2. press ADD button
3. edit the text I already done at the input area index[0] again, then I can't enter
   text well...

**My question is: why can't I edit the text I already inputted?**

---

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

function Item({ number, handleInput, handleAdd, handleDelete, index }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.list}>
      <Text>{index}</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{ borderWidth: 1 }}
        value={number[index]}
        onChangeText={(text) => {
          handleInput(index, text);
        }}
      ></TextInput>
      <Button
        title="ADD"
        onPress={() => {
          handleAdd();
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="DELETE"
        onPress={() => {
          handleDelete(index);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default function SOFStateArray() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const [number, setNumber] = useState([]);

  function handleAdd() {
    setCount((v) => v + 1);
  }

  function handleDelete(index) {
    setCount((v) => v - 1);
    setNumber((v) => {
      const ret = v.slice();
      ret.splice(index, 1);
      return ret;
    });
  }

  function handleInput(index, text) {
    setNumber((v) => {
      v.splice(index, 1, text);
      return v;
    });
  }

  // function handleInput(index, text) {
  //   setNumber((v) => {
  //     const ret = v.slice();
  //     ret.splice(index, 1, text);
  //     return ret;
  //   });
  // }

  return (
    <View>
      {Array.from({ length: count }, (_, i) => (
        <Item
          number={number}
          handleInput={handleInput}
          handleAdd={handleAdd}
          handleDelete={handleDelete}
          key={i + "-" + number}
          index={i}
        />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#ddd",
  },
});
```

---

Here is the first modified code(with roop to make components):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

function Item({ number, handleInput, handleAdd, handleDelete, index }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.list}>
      <Text>{index}</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{ borderWidth: 1 }}
        value={String(number)}
        onChangeText={(text) => {
          console.log(text);
          handleInput(index, text);
        }}
      ></TextInput>
      <Button
        title="ADD"
        onPress={() => {
          handleAdd();
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="DELETE"
        onPress={() => {
          handleDelete(index);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default function SOFStateArray() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const [numbers, setNumber] = useState([0]);

  function handleAdd() {
    setCount((v) => v + 1);
  }

  function handleDelete(index) {
    setCount((v) => v - 1);
    setNumber((v) => {
      const ret = v.slice();
      ret.splice(index, 1);
      return ret;
    });
  }

  function handleInput(index, text) {
    setNumber((v) => {
      v.splice(index, 1, text);
      return v;
    });
  }

  // function handleInput(index, text) {
  //   setNumber((v) => {
  //     const ret = v.slice();
  //     ret.splice(index, 1, text);
  //     return ret;
  //   });
  // }

  return (
    <View>
      {numbers.map((number, i) => (
        <Item
          number={number}
          handleInput={handleInput}
          handleAdd={handleAdd}
          handleDelete={handleDelete}
          key={i + "-" + number}
          index={i}
        />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#ddd",
  },
});
```

---

node : 12.18.3

react native : 4.10.1

expo : 3.22.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript array splice modifies the original array. And this means the array variable itself doesn't change. I suggest you to clone the original array, splice the cloned array and return it. This can work because react compares the old props to the new props and rerenders the component only when the props are different. For now, even though you removed an item from array, the array variable didn't change and it doesn't rerender the component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TextInput,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

function Item({text, handleInput, handleAdd, handleDelete, index}) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.list}>
      <Text>{index}</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{borderWidth: 1}}
        value={text}
        onChangeText={(t) => {
          handleInput(index, t);
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="ADD"
        onPress={() => {
          handleAdd();
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="DELETE"
        onPress={() => {
          handleDelete(index);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    texts: [''],
  };

  handleAdd = () => {
    const {texts} = this.state;
    this.setState({texts: [...texts, '']});
  };

  handleDelete = (index) => {
    const texts = [...this.state.texts];
    texts.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({texts: texts});
  };

  handleInput = (index, text) => {
    const {texts} = this.state;
    texts[index] = text;
    this.setState({texts});
  };

  render() {
    const {texts} = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
        <SafeAreaView>
          <View style={styles.body}>
            {texts.map((text, i) => (
              <Item
                key={'' + i}
                text={text}
                handleInput={this.handleInput}
                handleAdd={this.handleAdd}
                handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
                index={i}
              />
            ))}
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: I tried to change the code at `function handleInput` as bellow:
`function handleInput(index, text) {
    setNumber((v) => {
      const ret = v.slice();
      ret.splice(index, 1, text);
      return ret;
    });
  }`
in this case, I can't enter the text as usual even it is the first time.

Comment: No, it doesn't work...there is another bug...
when I enter some texts, TextInput /Input element loses focus on keypress...

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your code. Let me think how to solve it.

Comment: 1. I want you to loop with numbers, instead of Array.from.
2. I want you to modify your code so that item receives actual text instead of number and index.

Comment: I tried modifying the code with forEach, but it doesn't work well....could you share a sample code how I can loop with numbers?

Comment: I edited my answer to contain the sample code. Also, it will be better if you change number to numbers, for a more comprehensive meaning.

Comment: I changed the code to modify with roop code(I added the new code in question area), but it still doesn't work well. when I enter some texts, TextInput /Input element still loses focus on keypress...

Comment: Go back to your first handleInput method. I mean, do not clone array.

Comment: I changed the code to modify to go back the first handle input method, even though it doesn't work, this time the value never changes...

Comment: I checked the updated code and It works well, your support is so helpful for me, thank you so much for your help!!